# RegEx for ukrainian letters. How to separate cyrillic words by capital letter?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a String with some cyrillic words inside. Each starts with a capital letter.

```
var str = 'ХєлпМіПліз';
```

I have found this solution `str.match(/[А-Я][а-я]+/g)`.

But it returns me `["Пл"]` insted of `["Хєлп", "Мі", "Пліз"]`. Seems like it doesn't recognize ukrainian letters('і', 'є'), only russian.

So, How do I have to change that regex to include ukrainian letters?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: No; he just needs to change the regex to include the characters he wants.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`[А-Я]` is not Cyrillic alphabet, it's just Russian!

Cyrillic is a writing system. It used in alphabets for many languages.
(Like Latin: charset for West European languages, East European &c.)

To have both Russian and Ukrainian you'd get `[А-ЯҐЄІЇ]`.

To add Belarisian: `[А-ЯҐЄІЇЎ]`

And for all Cyrillic chars (including Balcanian languages and Old Cyrillic), you can get it through Unicode subset class, like: `\p{IsCyrillic}`

---

To deal with Ukrainian separately:

`[А-ЩЬЮЯҐЄІЇ]` or `[А-ЩЬЮЯҐЄІЇа-щьюяґєії]` seems to be full Ukrainian alphabet of 33 letters in each case.

Apostrophe is not a letter, but occasionally included in alphabet, because it has an impact to the next vowel.
Apostrophe is a part of the words, not divider. It may be displayed in a few ways:

```
27 "'" APOSTROPHE
60 "`" GRAVE ACCENT
2019 "’" RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
2bc "ʼ" MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE
```

and maybe some more.

Yes, it's a bit complicated with apostrophe. There is no common standard for it.

Comment: I don't get about `ЩЬЮЯ`.
Do they also have also different characters codes compared to Russian?

Comment: No, ЩЬЮЯ here to exclude ЫЪЭ (which are not from Ukrainian) from А-Я range.

Comment: oh, wow, didn't think about it.

But next question: what about "Ё"? Does it come in this order "...ЕЁЖЗ..."?
Do we need to improve regex and use this [А-EЖ-ЩЬЮЯҐЄІЇа-еж-щьюяґєії]?

Comment: Nope. Ё is out of А-Я range.

Comment: lol, it makes Cyrillic ranges not suitable for any language...

Answer (score 12):

Use `\p{Lu}` for uppercase match, `\p{Ll}` for lowercase, or `\p{L}` to match any letter

*update:*
That works only for Java, not for JavaScript.
Don't forget to include "apostrof", "ji" to your regexp

Comment: It's a good idea, but javascript doesn't have these character classes.

Comment: oops. sorry. didn't mention that it's js. That works for Java

Comment: and even my solution doen't include ukrainian "apostrof"

Answer (score 9):

Ukranian alphabet has four different words from the cyrillic alphabet, such as: [і, є, ї, ґ], also it can contain a single quote inside

```
"ґуля, з'їсти, істота, Європа".match(/[а-яієїґ\']+/ig)
```

`i` by the and will match the upper case, like with "Європа"

Answer (score 4):

The way to solve this is to look at the [unicode table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_characters) to determine the character ranges you need. If, for example, I use the pattern:

```
str.match(/[А-Я][а-яєі]+/g)
```

it works with your example string. (sorry i don't know ukrainian letters)

Answer (score 4):

`[А-Я][а-я]` really doesn't include ukranian letters.

While 'я' is `\u044f`, 'є' is `\u0454` and 'i' is `\u0456` (`\u0404` for Є ) . You should include them in regex by hand:

`/[А-ЯЄI][а-яєi]+/g`

Answer (score 3):

Only Ukrainian, without Russian

```
[бвгґджзклмнпрстфхцчшщйаеєиіїоуюяь]/gi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The letters might be right, but they aren't matching the other requirements (uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters). So I recommend updating your answer to include the other requirements as well.

Answer (score 2):

works with Ukrainian letters 'i' and others

```
python
r's/[^а-яА-Я.!?]/./g+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern below:

```
^[А-ЩЬЮЯҐЄІЇ][а-щьюяґєії']*$
```